# iOS keylogger for jailbroken devices

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, jailbreak, keylogger

I want to know how to implement a keylogger for iOS jailbroken iPhones and prevent being logged by others.

**1. Implementing a keylogger in iOS (jailbreak)**

I have thought of two ways to do this,

*First way:*

I hook `_endedEditing` method of class `UITextField` and save the text of the textfield somewhere. The advantage of this way is it's easy and it's not depending on what you typed. So if you have copied some text in the textfield, you would know that too. The problem is It's not called for text boxes in html webpages like google search bar or some programs that there keyboard doesn't hide.

*Second way:*

I should hook the keyboard buttons press method and save there labels. The keystrokes should be slit every time the keyboard hides. There is a problem here for me: First of all I can't find the right method of the right class to hook. I've found `UIKeyboardButton` that inherits from `UIButton` but when I hook any method of that it's not called, I don't know why!

So how can I implement a keylogger for iOS?

**2. Preventing an app being keylogged by a third party app/tweak**

Now the second part of my question; There is a keylogger in cydia named `iKeyMonitor` that logs keystrokes and it's good at its job. The suprising thing here is that it can't log whatever is typed in iFile app! I even have tested this with the first way I mentioned above and I can't receive any text when I type anything in iFile. How does iFile do this and how can we do the same thing for our app?

Comment: Please break this into two separate questions. (1 = key logger, 2 = prevent key logging).

Comment: @twodayslate How can that help me?

Comment: I guess in case of iFile in means that MobileSubstrate doesn't work. Don't know how it's now but there is always been a problem with root applications. The reason is they're launched not directly by executing binary but by executing small bash script first to give the application root permissions. Because of that all environment variables that MobileSubstrate set are ignored. You still can hook this kind of applications - you just need to set DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES manually in the bash script.